# Grab data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here website will list some data based on dropdown-filter, so i am trying to fetch those data by passing static dropdown values, but i think due to view state i am unable to grab those data.

> Anyone have any idea how to grab asp.net website data which is using viewstate?

i am getting below error

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

**Python Script**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_viewstate():
url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx?ST=GJ"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.text

bs = BeautifulSoup(data)
return bs.find("input", {"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).attrs['value']

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx?ST=GJ"
data = {"__VIEWSTATE": get_viewstate(),"ST":'GJ', "ddldistrict":'AMR', "ddltaluka":'' ,"btnSearch":'Search'}
req = requests.post(url, data)

bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
print(bs.prettify())
```

Comment: Give Selenium a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `requests` but you can easily do this with `selenium`.

To install selenium - `pip install selenium` or `pip3 install selenium`. 
Then download the latest `Chromedriver` from [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for your machine and copy the `driver` to your working directory.

You can read the `selenium` documentation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx?ST=GJ"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

#change this if you want to change the state from Gujrat to something else
#or you can change the state simply by changing the "?ST=GJ" part of the URL
#state = browser.find_element_by_id("ddlState")
#state.send_keys("BR")

district = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
district.send_keys("AMR")

#Skip this if you want to include all categories into the result
category = browser.find_element_by_id("ddlCategory")
category.send_keys("R")

button = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
button.click()

time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot(browser.title + ".JPEG")
html = browser.page_source
print(html)

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

**NOTE** 
If you want to use headless browser with `selenium`, use `PhantomJS`. To learn how to do this with `PhantomJS` read [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/).

Comment: hey MD. Khairul Basar can you help me to store each field value into mysql database?

Comment: @JunedAnsari Can give it a try.

Comment: Basar, finally i did to store data into mysqldatabase, now  can you help me to fetch dropdown values dynamically, instead of specifying static value, it is based on ajax next dropdown value fills. i am trying to store whole states dropdown values in array like wise

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277239/loop-dynamic-ajax-based-dropdown-values-using-python-selenium-and-grab-data-to-m