# Loop Dynamic Ajax Based Dropdown values using python selenium and grab data to mysql database

Tags: python, selenium

I am able to grab data if i apply static value of each dropdown but now i am trying to fetch dynamic values loop through each value of dropdown and store result to mysqldb.

> **Issue :** I am unable to loop each elements of drop-down and store result to database, if i pass static value for each three dropdown then i am able to do.

[image]

**Working Code for Static values**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

#=========State====================
state = browser.find_element_by_id("ddlState")
state.send_keys("GJ")

#=========District====================
district = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
district.send_keys("AD2")

#=========Taluka====================
category = browser.find_element_by_id("ddltaluka")
category.send_keys("AMB")

button = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
button.click()


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="", # your password
                      db="test") # name of the data base

cursor=db.cursor()


time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot(browser.title + ".JPEG")
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.findChildren('table')[3]

for row in table.findAll("tr")[1:]:
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    name = cells[0].find(text=True)
    city = cells[1].find(text=True)
    licence = cells[2].find(text=True)
    owner = cells[3].find(text=True)
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO distributors (name, city, licence, owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", (name, city, licence, owner))


#print(table.prettify())
#print(html)

db.commit()
db.close()

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

**Trying to pass dynamic values by looping each elements of dropdown**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

#=======================================================
#Array of Stats Dropdown
states_array = []
el = browser.find_element_by_id('ddlState')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    states_array.append(option.get_attribute("value"))


#print(states_array)
#=======================================================

#=======================================================
#Array of Districts Dropdown
district_array = []
el = browser.find_element_by_id('ddldistrict')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[1:]:
    district_array.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

#print(district_array)
#=======================================================


state = browser.find_element_by_id("ddlState")
district = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
category = browser.find_element_by_id("ddltaluka")


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="", # your password
                      db="test") # name of the data base
cursor=db.cursor()
taluka_array = []

for i in range(len(states_array)):
    state.send_keys(states_array[i])
for j in range(len(district_array)):
    district.send_keys(district_array[j])
    district.click()
    el = browser.find_element_by_id('ddltaluka')
        for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[1:]:
            taluka_array.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
        print(taluka_array)
for k in range(len(taluka_array)):  
    category.send_keys(taluka_array[k])
    button = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
    button.click()
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.findChildren('table')[3]
    for row in table.findAll("tr")[1:]:
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        name = cells[0].find(text=True)
        city = cells[1].find(text=True)
        licence = cells[2].find(text=True)
        owner = cells[3].find(text=True)
        cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO distributors (name, city, licence, owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", (name, city, licence, owner))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan! And your question/issue is?

Comment: i am unable to loop it for dynamic, you can see my try

Comment: Can you be much more explicit - what you expect to happen, what actually does happen, what specific issues you are facing - add this to the question pls, not in another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the `td` tag to filter out `states` then get the values of `option` tags. Here you get all the states. For each state go to the url of that state and find districts. Districts are in the 2nd `td` tag so use `find_next_sibling()` and again get the values of the `option` tags. So you find all the districts too for each state. And rest of the things you already did.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

states = [ x["value"] for x in soup.find("td", bgcolor="#ffe0c0").find_all("option") ]

for state in states:

    browser.get(url + "?ST=" + state)
    time.sleep(5)

    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    districts = [ x["value"] for x in soup.find("td", bgcolor="#ffe0c0").find_next_sibling().find_all("option") ]
    districts = districts[1:]

    for dist in districts:

        browser.get(url + "?ST=" + state)
        district = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
        district.send_keys(dist)

        button = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
        button.click()

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```